# Obtain offset and size from file for storing in a map

Tags: c++, json

I have a JSON file called short2.json which stores a tree in the following format:

```
{"id":442500001101774848, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":442501072373153792, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":442501562938966016, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":442502567265062912, "reply":1, "children":[]}]}]}]}
{"id":442500000258342912, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":442500636668489728, "reply":0, "children":[]}]}
```

I need to store the root of each tree in a hashmap along with a tuple for offset and byte-size of the line corresponding to the tree so that I can eventually do some search and copy the line from the exact location in the file into another file. For this, I will be needing the offset of every line in the file and the size of the line (or is there a better approach?)

I did the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        ifstream files("short2.json");
        string f;
        while (getline(files, f)) {
                fpos_t pos;
                fgetpos(files, &pos);
                cout << *pos << " " << sizeof(f) << endl;
        }
}
```

However on compiling, I get the following error:

```
readFile.cpp: In function âint main()â:
readFile.cpp:9:22: error: invalid conversion from âvoid*â to âFILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}â [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/stdio.h:795:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of âint fgetpos(FILE*, fpos_t*)â [-fpermissive]
readFile.cpp:10:12: error: no match for âoperator*â in â*posâ
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You are mixing C library functions with C++ library functions. `fgetpos` does not take a C++ stream. As the error clearly states, it expects a `FILE*`. You could try reading the documentation for functions that you use. Furthermore, why aren't you using [a JSON parser](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)?

Comment: could you please indicate which function i should use to get the position using in a C++ stream?

Comment: No. I'm going to kindly recommend that you get into the habit of performing basic research. Start [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Comment: I am not using a json parser, because I have a huge file (30 GB), and the real purpose why I am doing this business is so that I have short time access to the object of interest after storing it in a map. as of now, I am not much concerned about the values stored in the json object (other than the root). I am more concerned about accessing the required object from the file in a short time.

Comment: A JSON parser can still do it better than you. That's their job. Though if your JSON is really 30GB (wtf?!) then you'd probably want to be looking for a specialist one that streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for the pointers. Following is the code that I have come up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        ifstream files("short2.json");
        string f;
        while (getline(files, f)) {
                cout << files.tellg() - f.size() - 1 << " " << f.size() << endl;
        }
}
```